# Unable to call perl subroutine with paths as parameters from bash

Tags: perl

I am calling perl subroutine with paths as parameters from unix CLI mode.
But Getting  Bareword found error. Anyway to get through this.

```
[ssonnad@cycrh6rtp34 ~/test]**$perl -e "require qw(./burt.pm) ;file(/u/path,/u/build/);"**
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "/u/path"
    (Missing operator before path?)
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "/u/build"
    (Missing operator before build?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "/u/path"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.


    [ssonnad@cycrh6rtp34 ~/test]$ cat burt.pm 
    #!/usr/software/bin/perl5.8.8
    use strict;
    sub file
    {
      my ($path1, $path2) = @_;
      print "path1 $path1\n";
      print "path2 $path2\n";
    }
    1;
```

Comment: Put quotes around your strings.

Comment: Note that I tried adding double quotes to paths. Could not succeed

Comment: Double quotes don't nest. Use single quotes or q() or qq().

Comment: Put your perl in single quotes and the paths in double quotes?

Comment: Perfect choroba.  It worked. My question is looking silly now after reading your answer. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I have edited my question to suit my real time scenario.  I have to call perl subroutine from bash script.  I have to pass bash variables as parameters. I am unable to do it.

Comment: Your question is now something completely different. That's not how we do things here. My answer is now invalid, and will not help future users. You essentially wasted my time, and that of the two other users that commented. If you have a new question, please ask it in a fresh post.

Comment: I have corrected it. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Great, thank you. Now are you going to create a second question for the follow-up? I can answer that, but I didn't want to do it here as it's really something else.

Comment: hey. I got the answer for my other query as well. Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote your strings. You cannot use double quotes `""` to do that because you already use them for the shell parameter to the `-e` flag. Use single quotes `''` or the quote operators `q` or `qq` instead.

```
$ perl -e "require 'burt.pm'; file('/u/path', '/u/build');"
```

It is in general a good idea to use `q` in one-liners so not to interfere with the shell quoting.

In any case, on Linux systems you probably want to use single quotes `''` for the Perl program that goes after `-e`, because the double quotes `""` enable your shell's quoting mechanism.

In Perl, the double quotes `""` turn on interpolation, so variables and special characters get filled in. I would write your program like this:

```
$ perl -e 'require q{burt.pm}; file( q{/u/path}, q{/u/build} );'
```

Also note that Perl programs without the `strict` pragma will treat barewords as strings, but a slash `/` is not part of the bareword. Perl probably thinks there is a pattern match or a division going on, and that's a syntax error in this case.

Comment: Note that for Perl modules (`.pm` files) the naming convention is that the first letter is captial, the rest is small. Basically `ucfirst` camel case. All lower case names are reserved for pragmas such as `strict`, `warnings`, `re` or `utf8`.